# Can I anchor a safety harness with a ladder or the side of the house?

Tags: safety, roofing

I'm going to do some roof work and I plan on using a safety harness.  I'd like to avoid making any holes in the shingles to attach the harness anchor.  Could I instead attach the the safety line to a ladder on the opposite side of the house with the line thrown over the roof?  Or, perhaps could I attach the anchor to the opposite side of the house thrown over the roof?  Thanks.

Comment: Good for you for thinking safety. What pitch is the roof? (In other words, how steep is it? That’s usually expressed as rise over run, so a 5/12 roof goes up 5 units for every 12 units over.)

Comment: Assuming it's a gable roof, what kind of ridge is on top? If it's covered with curved shingles, they may crack underneath the pressure of twice your weight. I.e. your weight on one side, and part of something else (like a car) exerting exactly the same counterforce from the other side.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### CERTAINLY NOT A LADDER.

My biggest ladder weighs 50 lb. I weigh considerably more than that. If I tied myself to my biggest ladder and fell, I'd keep falling and the ladder would get yanked onto the roof.

Depending on the edges of your roof, probably not the walls, either - if the gutter or drip edge cuts your rope, there you go, falling all over again.

Best bet for most houses is probably to **permanently install** several on the peak of the roof with appropriate sealants. The peak is the place with the least water falling on it (no water comes from above other than direct rain) and you'll need them the next time, too. Since you are doing work on your (apparently shingled) roof, you can remove the cap shingle, seal the anchor screwed into the framing, and put new cap shingles cut to fit over it and sealed where it penetrates them - or use one on either side, so it does not penetrate, but comes out from under the cap shingle edge.

In some cases, with a long enough rope **and** rope damage protection along the roof edge, you may be able to anchor to a tree on the other side of the house.

Learn what a figure-8 follow-through knot is and use it, if going that way.

A hazard of tying off on the other side of the house is that your rope can fall off the end of the peak, depending where you are working, and will then provide no fall protection at all. An anchor at the peak does not have this problem. You may need to stop work and relocate your tie-off to reduce this risk. You must beware the common fault of not wanting to bother to do that.

Comment: "If I tied myself to my biggest ladder and fell, I'd keep falling and the ladder would get yanked onto the roof and then it would fall on me."  sounds like something Wile E. Coyote  would do.

Answer (score 3):

You are probably over 150 pounds, a ladder might be 50 pounds or less.

Guess how much the ladder will stop you from falling, you fall to the ground and then the ladder will fall on top of you.

Tie off the harness to an object that does not move. A brick chimney, structural members of the house/roof.

Using the wife's car is not good when she goes out with you tied to it.

Comment: If using a car/vehicle for an anchor, the person tied to it must have **all** the keys to it.

Comment: Another car tie-off trick is to bring the end of the rope into the car and tie it to the steering wheel as a reminder

Answer (score 0):

### Not a ladder unless you anchor the ladder to the ground

You can absolutely anchor yourself to the other side of roof, but I would recommend using a ring anchored into the concrete if available or something that is stationary like a tree or a fence post.

Comment: I picture this with an extension ladder where the bottom section is set into bedrock and the upper section has the rope to the harness attached. Hmm.

Comment: I don’t know if you were joking about the ladder part, but to be pedantic, all parts of a fall arrest system have to be listed for strength and a ladder isn’t a good link in that chain.